# Remix IDE shortcuts?

Tags: remix

I'm looking for a complete list of Remix IDE shortcuts. (Little things make a big difference, and I'm a big fan of efficiency). Through trial and error, here's what I found so far:

- Opt+Up/Down: Move line up/down
- CMD+D: Delete line
- CTR+OPT+Up/Down: Multicursor (super useful)

I would love to be able to CMD+D to highlight word like in Sublime. I've tried searching for Remix IDE shortcuts, searched the [doc](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=shortcut&check_keywords=yes&area=default), but found nothing...

Anybody have their own list or know of a source? Thanks!

Comment: what are shortcuts to comment lines or line on remix and same for undo the comments?

Comment: To comment and undo comment select the code and make ctrl + shift + A

Answer (score 2):

Remix uses the [Brace Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brace) package ([Github](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace)) for its editor window, so shortcuts are inherited from there.

Brace supports both [emacs and vim keybindings](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace/tree/032404bee863470d8fd81a860c227466d48206e2/keybinding). (I'm assuming the examples in your question are actually either emacs/vim shortcuts.)

Back in Remix, the `.addCommand()` method calls in [`editor.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/b52433aa7e123691481c9390dc504554a671f5c1/apps/remix-ide/src/app/editor/editor.js) add a few extra shortcuts on top.

**Edit:**

My emacs/vim chops are well out of date, so here's another method...

To edit all occurences of a given string:

- `Ctrl+f` to open the "Find" window
- Enter the string
- `Alt+Enter` to highlight all instances
- Type the new string

Comment: What do you mean by "Back in Remix, the .addCommand() method calls in editor.js add a few extra shortcuts on top." Can you elaborate? If you could just help me find out how to select all occurrences of a selected word, that would be great!

Comment: I've edited my answer. What I meant was, Remix inherits various keybindings from the Brace package, but then Remix itself adds some extra keybindings on top (as per the code in `editor.js`).

Answer (score 0):

const {MerkleTree} = require("merkletreejs"); // import merkletreejs
const keccak256 = require("keccak256");// import
let whitelistAddresses = [
"0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4" ,//A
"OxAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2", //B
"Ox4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db",//c
"Ox78731D3Ca6b7E34aC0F824c42a7cC18A495cabaB",//d
let leafNode = whitelistAddresses.map(addr=>keccak256(addr));//key=>value
//console.log(leafNode);
const merkleTree= new MerkleTree (leafNode);//object //console.log(merkleTree);
const rootHash = merkleTree.getRoot();
//console.log (rootHash);
//claiming address const claimingAddress="0×583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225" ;
// get proof
const hexProof = merkleTree.getProof(claimingAddress);
console. log(hexProof)
//verification
const isProofValid = merkleTree.verify(hexProof, claimingAddress, merkleTree.getRoot());
console.log("Is proof valid?", isProofValid);

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Array {
uint[5] public staticArray = [1, 2, 3]; // Static array
uint[] public dynamicArray = [1, 2]; // Dynamic array

```
// Addition of array elements
function additionofElements(uint index, uint element) public {
    staticArray[index] = element;//static array
    dynamicArray.push(element);//dynamic
}

// Deletion of static array element
function deletionofStatic(uint index) public {
    delete staticArray[index];
}

// Deletion of dynamic array element
function deletionofDynamic() public {
    dynamicArray.pop(); // Remove the last element from the array
}

// Finding length of a given array
function getlength() public view returns (uint, uint) {
    return (staticArray.length, dynamicArray.length);
}
 //d. Printing array elements in sorted order
function printSortedDynamicArray() public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    uint[] memory sortedArray = dynamicArray;
    bubbleSort(sortedArray);
    return sortedArray;
}

// Simple bubble sort algorithm for sorting the array
//internal so that Frontend can't give input of array
function bubbleSort(uint[] memory arr) internal pure {
    uint n = arr.length;
    for (uint i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                // Swap arr[j] and arr[j + 1]
                (arr[j], arr[j + 1]) = (arr[j + 1], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//e.    Searching a particular element in an array 
function search(uint value) public view returns(bool) {
    uint[5] memory array2 = staticArray; //gas optimization
    for(uint i=0;i<staticArray.length;i++){
       if(array2[i]==value){
        return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}